# Do some nonlinear PDE steady state solutions depend on initial conditions (non unique)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, initial-value-problems, nonlinear-dynamics, steady-state

I was told by a colleague that for some nonlinear PDEs the initial conditions can change the steady-state solution.

So can a stable steady solution depend on the initial conditions for nonlinear PDEs?

This goes against my understanding of differential equations. I suppose this is related to not being guaranteed uniqueness. I am doing numerical simulations where I have coupled multiple models together that are nonlinear.

I feel I have seen this effect in my model. This is deeply worrying to me as any predictive useful model has to be unique. Certainly, the transient should depend on initial conditions but I can't imagine a physical scenario where a stable steady-state solution could depend on initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can (and does) happen.

Consider the following (separable!) ODE: $$\frac{dU}{dt}=U-U^3\tag{1}$$  Solutions to (1) are one of the following (for some constant of integration $C$): \begin{gather*}
U(t)=0 \\
U(t)=\pm(1+Ce^{-2t})^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{gather*}  In particular, as $t\to\infty$, we have $$U(t)\to\begin{cases}
1 & U(0)>0 \\
0 & U(0)=0 \\
-1 & U(0)<0
\end{cases}$$

To adapt this to the PDE case, just consider (1) as describing the partial derivative of a function $U(x)$ with respect to time.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!  I get that the solution branch (+/-) is determined by the initial conditions and that is a valid point tending it to +/- 1 as a result and that you can keep both solutions with U(0)=0 so they just cancel for all of time giving 0. However, I am modeling densities and temperatures of ions which are always positive so I would always be starting with a + branch but nonetheless, something similar could possibly happen with my nonlinear diffusion equations coupled to a physical chemistry model. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still concerned that this type of model can't correspond to a physical system.

Comment: @E.Nerney: Positivity is something of a red herring here.  If $V=U+1$, then $V$ is always positive, but tends to $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: @E.Nerney: This sort of thing _definitely_ happens in physical chemistry.  Consider a body of liquid silica, on a hill.  In the valley on the right is a block of ice; in the valley on the left just sand.  If you place the silica just to the right of the hump, it flows towards the ice and quickly cools to glass; if slightly to the left, it will cool slowly into a block of sand.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I am trying to reproduce a physical system and match observations of the Io Plasma torus within the magnetosphere of Jupiter. I am assuming they correspond to a steady-state (though I do model transient volcanic eruptions from Io changing chemistry but the system is fairly stable otherwise). I suppose I should try starting me solution closer to the 3D structure I am trying to match and it should help it converge to a solution closer to that if such a solution exists.